# Jetpack compose deeplink does not save previous composable's state

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am navigating to a deep-level screen via the deep link in my app. However, as there is no controller navigation through the previous screen to my deep link, the state of the last screen is ignored. I don't want to navigate to the deep link as the screen manually I want to navigate to can be accessed from anywhere and I don't want to put that logic everywhere. Any suggestions?

I am using jetpack compose navigation.

Comment: Can you provide some code of your current solution?